# Focus on the new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I need all your help for the following approach.

My requirement is

1) Loading a page with two tabs namely SEARCH and DETAILS.
2) By default DETAILS tab should not be enabled.
3)In Search Page, on retriving the result set, on click of result set the details should be populated on DETAILS tab. The Second tab should be enabled onclick and focus also needs to shift to DETAILS tab.
4)Navigation between both tabs should be smooth.

I am currently working on Struts 1.3.

Could anyone guide me on this?

Comment: do you mean `browser`'s tab?

Comment: No user defined tabs.. using jquery

Comment: I think the tabs are jquery-ui tabs. What have you tried so far? It doesn't sound very difficult.

Comment: I have tried setting the focus on the tab. but my details are not opening the tab. ie basically focus is not shifting. Yes i am using jquery-ui-tabs

Answer (score 0):

create tab with `active: 0` (assuming index of `search` tab is 0 that is it is the first tab) on click event of tab heading of `details` create tab again with `active: 0` on search validation `unbind` `click` event from `details tab` and trigger `click` on `a` tag inside the heading `li` of `details` tab once `details tab` is opened again bind it's click event to create `tabs` with `active: 0`

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Search</a></li>
    <li id="deactive"><a href="#tabs-2">Details</a></li>  //add id deactive
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <input id="search" type="text" />
    <button>Search</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  active: 0
});

$('#deactive').click(function () {

    $('#tabs').tabs({

        active: 0 //refer to api documentation of jquery ui-tabs
    })
})

$('button').click(function () {
     var value = $('#search').val().toLowerCase()

     if (value == " your comparison/validation criteria ") {

         $('#deactive').unbind('click')
         $('#deactive >a').trigger('click')

         $('#deactive').click(function () {

             $('#tabs').tabs({
                 active: 0 //refer to api documentation of jquery ui-tabs
             })
         })
     }
})
```

[**CLICK HERE FOR DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PAm5t/)

[**DEMO FOR POPULATING DETAILS TAB ON THE BASIS OF SEARCH**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/PAm5t/2/)

**NOTE** that this will keep the `DETAILS TAB` disabled all time, if you don't want this behavior you have to tailor the code as per your requirement

Comment: Thank @UDB .. I will try your solution and will let u know

Comment: @Priya you can also assign an `id` to the `search` heading 'li' for example `<li id="active"><a href="#tabs-1">Search</a></li>` and then instead of calling `$('#tabs').tab({active: 0})` in `#deactive`'s click event's callback you can use `$('#active>a').click()`